# create an array of integer from 0 to 255 in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

Hi I want to create an array containing integers from 0 to 255 using a loop to store those integers into the array in MIPS assembly.
Im new in assembly
Thanks

Comment: Without an attempt to do so fromyou, you aren't going to get much help.  Use the magic google to see if you can get a close solution and work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, This is somewhat tough for new users to figure out, and then write out. I'll explain how one can achieve this, so that you know what to research in order to finish this. Assembly functions on such a low level of operation in terms of computer architecture. Assembly directly translates into commands that a cpu can process. This is why every command is on a line. One line translates to one operation that the cpu knows how to perform.

The cpu can do things like add or subtract or compare two numbers, but it only works with number values. In an operation, the cpu can perform an operation like add, and then save the data somewhere. This is the part I assume you are familiar with. This saved data must be stored someplace. This data very literally translates into binary 1s and 0s. At this level of operation we are not storing data in usual RAM memory. We are currently executing commands on the CPU so we are using its on board memory. This memory is called the stack. It has super fast access, but not even enough space to store your array. To store your array you will need to create it by explicitly filling spaces in memory in an incremental order. You can use `Store byte` to do this, and in a loop store all of the values in sequential order. `Store byte` allows you to save data to a literal address in RAM space so that you can access it later. However, you will need to store a variable that contains this memory address for the start of your array or you will have no way to know where your array is. Accessing your array will then require some overhead because you only really have a pointer to its beginning. Anytime you want to return some data from within it, you will have to transverse your addresses to access what you are looking for.

Here is a link that explains store byte among other commands that you will use to do this:
http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html